# Have to run macro twice "Delete row if cell contains numbers"

Tags: excel, vba

I have to run the Sub `twice` to delete all row if cell contains numbers

I cant figure out whats not working

Thanks

```
Sub DoesCellHaveNumer()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim acell As Range
Dim LR As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = ws.Range("B2:B" & LR)

    For Each acell In Rng
        If HasNumber(acell) = True Then acell.EntireRow.Delete
    Next acell

End Sub
```

.

```
Function HasNumber(strData As Variant) As Boolean
Dim iCnt As Integer

For iCnt = 1 To Len(strData)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(strData, iCnt, 1)) Then
        HasNumber = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next iCnt

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete row in loop, your loop becomes skewed. One way to fix it - backward loop, however faster one is:

```
Sub DoesCellHaveNumer()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim acell As Range
    Dim rngToDel As Range
    Dim LR As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    With ws
        LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range("B2:B" & LR)
    End With


    For Each acell In Rng
        If HasNumber(acell) Then
            If rngToDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngToDel = acell
            Else
                Set rngToDel = Union(rngToDel, acell)
            End If
        End If
    Next acell

    If Not rngToDel Is Nothing Then rngToDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the coda as well as the explination